# File table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to use a file table in SQL Server 2012.

When I create the file table Table, 1 folder create in file stream directory, but name of the folder is not equal to my file table Table!

I am using the following code;

```
CREATE TABLE Article AS FILETABLE
  WITH
  (
    FILETABLE_DIRECTORY = 'Article',
    FILETABLE_COLLATE_FILENAME =database_default
  )
```

and the name of the folder created in my stream directory is like `57e3f857-e888-4c0b-9814-d3c3880875d8` but when I paste a file to this folder and select this table

```
select * from Article
```

it returns empty result.

Comment: Are you inserting a record in your table to associate with your file?

Comment: @Jake i copy and paste file in windows explorer